# how to make animated bullet image?

Tags: html, css

I know in css, the unordered list bullet image can be change by following code:
ul { list-style-image: url(image)}

can I use an animation like

```
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: blue;}
}
```

as the bullet image? if not, then how to use animated image as bullet image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color of the bullet you need to modify the `color` property of the list but this will make your text color change too, so you need to wrap your text inside other element, like a `<span>` and modify its color too.

Then you can create a `keyframe` animation with the `color` property changing and apply it to the list as you did.

```css
ul li {
  color: red;
  animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

ul li span {
  color: black;
}

@keyframes animate {
 0% {
   color: red;
 }
 50% {
   color: blue;
 }
 100% {
   color: red;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
  <li><span>Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is becoming easier with new features in Chrome and Firefox so keep updated!

Btw it is not related to javascript